# Unable to change CSS for modified theme in Drupal

Tags: css, drupal, themes

I am new to Drupal. I have added a content with custom  `div`s to my homepage.eg

```
<div id="dest_objectives">
OBJECTIVES
</div>

<div id="dest_news_events">
NEWS AND EVENTS
</div>

<div id="dest_founder">
ABOUT FOUNDER
</div>
```

I am using(enabled and default) a custom theme `destination-theme`,which is a copy from `professional-theme`. Now I edited my `css` for path `sites/all/destination-theme/style.css`,but when I refreshed the url, it is not changing according to edited css. whats wrong I am doing?

Comment: have you cleared the cache?

Comment: "Now I edited my css for path 'site..."? You mean you edited the stylesheet at the path site/...?

Answer (score 0):

frist you have to confirm your theme is enabled which one you mentioned in your path

```
sites/all/destination-theme
```

after that check in your head section after page load your css file style.css is loaded or not
if loaded then it should be look like

```
@import url("http://www.domain.com/sites/all/themes/destination-theme/style.css?mla8o3");
```

it is not possible css file loaded and not efacting unless other css file orver write it

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your themes belong in sites/all/themes/ not in the root of the "all" directory. I don't know if your theme will work there, but that's not the "right" place

Also, do you intend to subtheme "destination-theme"? There's more to creating a subtheme (and all the advantages of using subthemeing) than using a copy of a theme directory: http://drupal.org/node/225125

Secondly, Firebug/Inspector will show you where your css files as network resources are being loaded from, regardless. What say it?